# Search bar with only characters in my search

Tags: laravel

In my search bar, I would like restrict my request like: the numbers or the symbols and keep only characters in my search. The user can only enter a name in the request.

I am stuck in my function...

```
public function index(Request $req){

     if($req->search == ""){
            $students = Student::paginate(5);
           return view('admin.students.index', compact('students'));
     } else {
          $students = Student::where('nom', 'LIKE', '%' .$req->search . '%')
        ->paginate(5);
        $students->appends($req->only('search'));
        return view('admin.students.index', compact('students'));
     }  

    }
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a validation for it to be `alpha` characters only:

```php
public function index(Request $req)
{
    if ($req->has('search') && !empty($req->search)) {
        // validate here
        $validated = $req->validate([
            'search' => 'alpha', // must be entirely alphabetic characters
        ]);

        $students = Student::where('nom', 'LIKE', '%' . $validated['search'] . '%')->paginate(5);
        $students->appends($req->only('search'));
        return view('admin.students.index', compact('students'));
    }

    $students = Student::paginate(5);
    return view('admin.students.index', compact('students'));
}
```

If validation fails, it will redirect back immediately with error messages you need to display.

---

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-alpha

> **alpha**
>   The field under validation must be entirely alphabetic characters.

Comment: I have a error message `Undefined variable: request` . This line is not good?  `$validated = $request->validate([
            'search' => 'alpha', 
        ]);`

Comment: Yeah sorry, by default it is $request, you are using $req. Updated my answer. :)

Comment: I have `Undefined index: search` but your old code was ok... :-)

Comment: `public function index(Request $req)
    {
    if ($req->search == "") {
        $students = Student::paginate(5);
        return view('admin.students.index', compact('students'));

    } else {
        // validate here
        $validated = $req->validate([
            'search' => 'alpha', // must be entirely alphabetic characters
        ]);

        $students = Student::where('nom', 'LIKE', '%' . $validated['search'] . '%')->paginate(5);
        $students->appends($req->only('search'));
        return view('admin.students.index', compact('students'));
         }
    }`

Comment: My code example shows one way to do that, and both answers link to the manual pages for Laravel Validation.

Comment: See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#working-with-error-messages

Answer (score 2):

### HTML5

First protect your field, to give the user immediate feedback to the user.  In your form blade:

```
<input type="text" name="search" value="{{ isset($search) ? $search : '' }}" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" placeholder="search" />
```

### Validation

[validate](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation) the search string to [alpha numeric](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-alpha-num):

```
$this->validate($reqest,[
    'search' => 'alpha_num',
]);
```

or just [alpha](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-alpha):

```
$this->validate($request,[
    'search' => 'alpha',
]);
```

### Newer Versions

Newer versions ([5.6+](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation)), requests can validate themselves instead of the controller, and return the validated fields for more protection, so the same thing would look like:

```
$data = $request->validate([
    'search'=>'alpha',
]);
```

### Showing Validation Errors

Taking the HTML5 input above and adding the code to [show validation errors](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors) to it so we can see when there is an error. We get a form that looks like:

```
<form method="get" action="{{route('student.index')}}">
    <input type="text" name="search" value="{{ isset($search) ? $search : '' }}" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" placeholder="search" />
    @if ($errors->has('search'))
        <div class="error">{{ $errors->first('search') }}</div>
    @endif
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

### Putting it Together

Applying that to your code:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->validate([
        'search' => 'alpha',
    ]);
    $students = isset($data['search']) ? Student::where('nom','like','%' . $data['search'] . '%')->paginate(5) : Student::paginate(5);
    return view('admin.students.index', compact('students','search'));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ... I just copy / paste your function, when I do a search, nothing happens ... :-(
Have I forgotten a few things?

Comment: What exactly does "nothing happens" mean?  Do you mean the page submits, but nothing changes?

Comment: Sorry, when I type a name, the filter can not find the record

Comment: So, you get back an empty table?  I've made a slight modification to the answer that should fix that, if it was an issue with my answer.

Comment: And another to make the function shorter, as the conditional is no longer required.

Comment: always the same problem but there is another solution on the forum the friend! Thank you for your time, I also take that from your code `pattern =" [a-zA-Z] + "`

Comment: Keep in mind like is case sensitive.  so searching for "Sam" will not find "sam".